# OpengGL ES 2.0 Billboard: What's wrong with this maths?

Tags: view, opengl-es-2.0, projection

Pasted below is pseudocode for two methods I've discovered online to generate a billboard transformation matrix for a 3d object in a scene. EDIT: Please note this is for an object which could have many more than 4 vertices - I'm attempting to calculate the full billboard transformation matrix for a 3d object, not a "single-quad-facing-the-camera" billboard.

This transformation is intended to orientate an object (the "billboard") to face the camera while remaining upright.

Neither of the two methods has worked, in most cases displaying nothing in my scene i.e. the coordinates have been transformed out of view.

Can anyone identify whether there's a flaw in the calculations or in the ordering of matrix multiplications in the shader code line? I'd be very grateful for your advice.

```
// Vectors:
//
// bbPos    Billboard position.
// bbUp     Billboard up vector.
// bbRight  Billboard right vector.
//
// camPos   Camera position.
// camUp    Camera up vector.
// camRight Camera right vector.

// Approach 1:
vec3 bbLook = bbPos - camPos;
bbLook.normalize();

vec3 bbRight = cross(camUp, bbLook);
bbRight.normalize();

vec3 bbUp = cross(bbLook, bbRight);
bbUp.normalize();

mx4 a_billboard = (     bbRight.x,  bbRight.y,  bbRight.z,  0.0f,
                bbUp.x,     bbUp.y,     bbUp.z,     0.0f,
                bbLook.x,   bbLook.y,   bbLook.z,   0.0f,
                bbPos.x,    bbPos.y,    bbPos.z,    1.0f);

// Approach 2:
vec3 bbLook = camPos - bbPos;
bbLook.normalize();

vec3 bbRight = cross(camUp, bbLook);
bbRight.normalize();

vec3 bbUp = cross(bbLook, bbRight);
bbUp.normalize();

mx4 a_billboard = ( bbRight.x,  bbUp.x,     bbLook.x,   bbPos.x,
            bbRight.y,  bbUp.y,     bbLook.y,   bbPos.y,
            bbRight.z,  bbUp.z,     bbLook.z,   bbPos.z,
            0.0f,       0.0f,       0.0f,       1.0f);
```

In the vertex shader, the following code combines the p(rojection), wv(view * world), m(odel) and billboard matrices:

```
    gl_Position = p * a_billboard * wv * m * vec4(a_position.xyz, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheers, the first flaw is that you modify your bbUp vector. That needs to stay fixed (if you change it, how do you expect it to *remain* upright?). You can use:

```
vec3 bbUp = vec3(0, 1, 0); // up
```

and:

```
vec3 bbLook = bbPos - camPos;
bbLook.normalize();

vec3 bbRight = cross(bbUp, bbLook);
bbRight.normalize();
// calculate right vector from look vector
```

or:

```
vec3 bbRight = camRight - bbUp * dot(bbUp, camRight); // use the Gram-Schmidt process
bbRight.normalize();
// just take camRight and make it orthogonal to bbUp
```

The bbLook vector needs to be recalculated in both cases as cross product of bbUp and bbRight afterwards. So that's what was wrong with your math.

The other thing that is wrong, is rendering billboards using matrix is not effective since you need one such matrix per billboard. It is better to store billboard centers positions in vertex attribute array and use texture coordinates to calculate billboard vertices (that means billboard center position repeated 4 times with different texcoords). An example:

```
float[] billboard = {x, y, z, 0, 0, x, y, z, 1, 0, x, y, z, 1, 1, x, y, z, 0, 1};
```

That enables you to draw many billboards at once, using vertex shader such as this:

```
attribute vec3 vCenter;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

uniform matrix4 mvp;

uniform vec3 bbUp, bbRight;

varying vec2 texCoordOut;

void main()
{
    vec3 corner = vCenter + (texCoord.x - .5) * 2.0 * bbRight +
                            (texCoord.y - .5) * 2.0 * bbUp;
    // this calculates corner position (texcoords need to be rescaled from [0 1] to [-1 1])

    gl_Position = mvp * corner;
    texCoordOut = texCoord;
    // write position, texcoords
}
```

This makes it possible to render many billboards with the same up- and right- vectors. You may, however, supply the up-vectors as another vertex attribute so that each of your billboards have it's own axis. You can check out a little demo here: http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~ipolok/tam/10_Billboarding.zip

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'd appreciate some clarification. Firstly, are you aware that I have no `bbUp` value before the `vec3 bbUp = ....` line? You suggest I calculate bbLook from bbUp x bbRight, but actually since I must work out `bbLook` first, I do `bbLook x bbRight` instead. Secondly, the texture example you show is useful only for a 4-point billboard I believe, i.e. a quad. This is not what I'm trying to achieve; I have a full 3d object which I want to face the camera, composed of much more than 4 vertices.

Comment: Firstly, bbUp = vec3(0, 1, 0), there you have it. Secondly, you are right, you calculate bbLook from difference of positions of billboard and camera. What i propose is, after calculating bbRight, update bbLook using cross product. That is perfectly valid. Thirdly, "Oh yeah, an object." Then what you are doing makes sense.

Comment: Thinking about it, the matrix you need is a simple lookAt matrix, with position being billboard position, target being camera position and upvector being the direction you want your billboard to be up (that can be (0, 1, 0) for the up up, or camera.up for screenspace up). Look that up ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will investigate tonight. Labelling this new matrix as 'M_BB', would this mean I need my shader to do world-view-projection calculation: p * v * w * M_BB  or p * v * M_BB * w?

Comment: That should be p * (v * (M_BB * w)) where v is view and w is world. The operator associativity should do the trick and so the parentheses are not necessary. I'd suggest trying with w being unit matrix if there is any trouble.